Help Needed: Uniswap Not Finding My Recently Deployed Smart Contract
Help Needed: Uniswap Not Finding My Recently Deployed Smart Contract
Hello everyone,
I’m facing some issues with Uniswap and could really use your expertise. I recently deployed a smart contract for my new token to start learning, on the Binance Smart Chain (BSC). The contract has been verified and published on BSCscan, and everything seems to be in order on that end; here is the contract address 0xEdE0E6dA9b01B47dC9C48c5160F3E3Ab9EfA553B. However, when I try to add the token on Uniswap, it’s not able to find the smart contract. Here are the steps I’ve taken so far:

Deployed the Smart Contract: Successfully deployed the contract on BSC.
Verification: Verified and published the contract on BSCscan.
Contract Address: Double-checked the contract address to ensure it is correct.
Liquidity Addition: Attempted to add liquidity on Uniswap, but the token isn’t recognized.

Despite these steps, Uniswap does not seem to recognize or find the smart contract. I'm not sure if there's an additional step I'm missing or if there might be an issue with compatibility or configuration.
Has anyone else faced a similar issue or does anyone have suggestions on what I might be missing? Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
W. Haddad

Steps:

Connect Wallet
Switch chain to BNB Chain
Choose Pools
Choose v2 version
Add v2 liquidity
Choose first token whichever you want to add liquidity with.
Choose 2nd your new token and approve it.
Add liquidity

For more detailed reference, please check the link attached here
